# Is it possible to send a list of files and a whole json object in a FormData object to a ASP.NET CORE MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, form-data

Just like the title says, how do I send  a formdata object to a mvc controller with both a json object (including nested objects) and list of files.
I have already tried to stringify the object to a json object but the controller can not read the property, it reads the file list without problems.

Here is the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
     public IActionResult CreateTask(Task task, IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
        {

            //some code
        }
```

here is my javascript:

```
function createTask() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var files = //some file objects

        var obj = {
            //some parameters 
        };


        var task = JSON.stringify(task);
        formData.append("task", task);
        formData.append("files", files);


        console.log(task);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Task/CreateTask",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (data) {

            }
        })

    }
```

I need the controller method to read both the task and the file list at the same time if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be to bind the JSON sent as `task` to a string server-side. Then, you'd have to manually deserialize it into an object. In case it's not obvious, that also means you won't get any validation on any of the members of that JSON object. It will just be a string as far as ASP.NET Core and the modelbinder is concerned.

That said, I think the issue here is that you're needing to upload files and think that that necessitates posting as `multipart/form-data`. You can actually post as JSON and yet still include file uploads. That requires two changes, though:

1. You must bind the file "uploads" to `byte[]`s, instead of `IFormFile`s, server-side.
2. Client-side, you must add them to the JSON object you're posting as either Base64-encoded strings or uint8 arrays.

The first part is relatively straight-forward. The JSON deserializer invoked by the modelbinder will automatically convert Base64-encoded strings to byte array, and of course a JS unint8 array is essentially just a byte array, anyways.

The second part probably bears a bit more discussion. You'll need to need to use the File API to read the upload file data, and then convert that into either a Base64-encoded string or uint8 array:

**Base64**

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    let base64 = btoa(reader.result);
    myJsonObject.files.push(base64);
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

**Byte Array**

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    let bytes = Array.from(new Uint8Array(reader.result));
    myJsonObject.files.push(bytes);
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert object to form-data like below:

1. View

   ```
           <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function () {
                   $("input").change(function () {
                       var formData = new FormData();
                       var files = $("#files")[0].files;

                       var obj = {
                           id: 1,
                           name: "jack"
                       };
                       for (var key in obj) {
                           formData.append(key, obj[key]);
                       }
                       for (var key in files) {
                           formData.append("files", files[key]);
                       }


                       $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "/api/values/CreateTask",
                           processData: false,
                           contentType: false,
                           data: formData,
                           success: function (data) {

                           },
                           error: function (data) {

                           }
                       })

                   });
               });
           </script>
   ```
2. Controller

   ```
           [HttpPost]
           public IActionResult CreateTask([FromForm]Task task, [FromForm]IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
           {
               return Ok("Success");
           }
   ```